# Php Formatter fix

Tags: php, formatter

I install php formatter (vs code [extesion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sophisticode.php-formatter)) and I have a problem with format file. It format php short echo tag (`<?=`) in `< ? =` (with spaces). There is a possibility to format the document without touching the tags `<?php`, `<?=` and the rest of the nearby tags ?